# $\frac{P(x)}{x^2+3}$ is $2x+5$, find the remainder of $\frac{[P(x)]^2}{x^2+3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility

The remainder of $\frac{P(x)}{x^2+3}$ is $2x+5$
$$$$
Find the remainder of
$$\frac{[P(x)]^2}{x^2+3}$$
The approach I have attempted for this exercise is to write $P(x)=(x^2+3)Q_1(x)+2x+5 ...(1)$ and also
$$[P(x)]^2=(x^2+3)Q_2(x)+ax+b...(2)$$
Now, in (1):
$$[P(x)]^2=(x^2+3)^2Q_1^2(x)+4x^2+25+4x(x^2+3)Q_1(x)+20x+10(x^2+3)Q_1(x)$$
For the remainder the only terms I need to consider are lineal and independent, given that the degree of $x^2+3$ is $2$, but I have had struggles, because $Q_1(x), Q_2(x)$ degrees are unknown, and that's where I get stuck. Any other way to approach this exercise or hint to continue with what I am doing?

Comment: $\bmod x^2+3\!:\ P\equiv 2x\!+\!5\Rightarrow P^2\equiv (2x\!+\!5)^2.\,$ Expand that using $\,x^2\equiv -3\,$ to get the sought remainder.

Comment: Thank you so much, by doing this, I actually got the correct answer!

Answer (score -1):

Your expression for $[P(x)]^2$ can be rewritten

$$Q_3(x)(x^2+3) + 4x^2+20x+25.$$

It doesn't matter what the degree of $Q_3$ is.  All you have to do is divide $4x^2+20x+25$ by $x^2+3.$